# How to use logstash

Tags: logstash

I want to use Logstash to analyze console logs and use them in an application but can somebody tell me how Logstash works?
Also can I run it on windows 8 desktop version or does it only run in the Server version?
Are there any other log processing software which is better than Logstash?

Comment: "How Logstash works" is a too broad question and "what's better" is primarily opinion-based. What I _can_ say is that Logstash runs on any version of Windows 8.

Comment: The main part I wanted was if it works on the desktop version. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Asma It runs on any version of windows 8, you need to have a relatively recent JVM however.

As for how things work: It's probably best if you take a look at the official tutorial or one of the various blog posts out there.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html

Other log aggregators include Graylog, splunk, Loggly, ...

Comment: @asma zinneera jabir please accept my answer if you liked it/it was helpful tu you. Thanks.